# Save contents of those files which contain a specific known string in an single .txt or .tmp file using perl

Tags: perl

I'm trying to write a perl script where I'm trying to save whole contents of those files which contain a specific string 'PYAG_GENERATED', in a single .txt/.tmp file one after another. These file names are in a specific pattern and this pattern is 'output_nnnn.txt' where nnnn is 0001,0002 and so on. But I don't know how many number of files are present with this 'output_nnnn.txt' name. 
I'm new in perl and I don't know how I can resolve this issue to get the output correctly. Can anyone help me. Thanks in advance.

I've tried to write perl script in different ways but nothing is coming in output file. I'm giving here one of those I've tried. 'new_1.txt' is the new file where I want to save the expected output and "PYAG_GENERATED" is that specific string I'm finding for in the files.

```
open(NEW,">>new_1.txt") or die "could not open:$!";
$find2="PYAG_GENERATED";
$n='0001';
while('output_$n.txt'){
    if(/find2/){
    print NEW;
    }
    $n++;
}
close NEW;
```

I expect that the output file 'new_1.txt' will save the whole contents of the the files(with filename pattern 'output_nnnn.txt') which have 'PYAG_GENERATED' string at least once inside.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you tried I guess.

Welcome to the wonderful world of Perl where there are always a dozen ways of doing X :-) One possible way to achieve what you want. I put in a lot of comments I hope are helpful. It's also a bit verbose for the sake of clarity. I'm sure it could be golfed down to 5 lines of code.

```
use warnings;  # Always start your Perl code with these two lines, 
use strict;    # and Perl will tell you about possible mistakes

use experimental 'signatures';

use File::Slurp;

# this is a subroutine/function, a block of code that can be called from 
# somewhere else. it takes to arguments, that the caller must provide

sub find_in_file( $filename, $what_to_look_for ) 
{
    # the open function opens $filename for reading 
    # (that's what the "<" means, ">" stands for writing)
    # if successfull open will return we will have a "file handle" in the variable $in
    # if not open will return false ... 
    open( my $in, "<", $filename )
        or die $!; # ... and the program will exit here. The variable $! will contain the error message

    # now we read the file using a loop
    # readline will give us the next line in the file
    # or something false when there is nothing left to read
    while ( my $line = readline($in) )
    {
        # now we test wether the current line contains what
        # we are looking for.
        # the index function gives us the index of a string within another string.
        # for example index("abc", "c") will give us 3
        if ( index( $line, $what_to_look_for ) > 0 )
        {
            # we found what we were looking for
            # so we don't need to keep looking in this file anymore
            # so we must first close the file
            close( $in );

            # and then we indicate to the caller the search was a successfull
            # this will immedeatly end the subroutine
            return 1;
        }
    }

    # If we arrive here the search was unsuccessful
    # so we tell that to the caller
    return 0;
}


# Here starts the main program
# First we get a list of files
# we want to look at
my @possible_files = glob( "where/your/files/are/output_*.txt" );

# Here we will store the files that we are interested in, aka that contain PYAG_GENERATED
my @wanted_files;

# and now we can loop over the files and see if they contain what we are looking for
foreach my $filename ( @possible_files )
{
    # here we use the function we defined earlier
    if ( find_in_file( $filename, "PYAG_GENERATED" ) )
    {
        # with push we can add things to the end of an array
        push @wanted_files, $filename;
    }
}

# We are finished searching, now we can start adding the files together
# if we found any
if ( scalar @wanted_files > 0 )
{
    # Now we could code that us ourselves, open the files, loop trough them and write out
    # line by line. But we make life easy for us and just
    # use two functions from the module File::Slurp, which comes with Perl I believe
    # If not you have to install it
    foreach my $filename ( @wanted_files )
    {
        append_file( "new_1.txt", read_file( $filename ) );
    }

    print "Output created from " . (scalar @wanted_files) . " files\n";
}
else
{
    print "No input files\n";
}
```

Comment: It's working. Thanks a lot. Really there are dozens of ways to write a problem code in Perl. Below I've given another code that I did before getting this solution and that worked also. Really Interesting.

Answer (score 0):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my @a;
my $i=1;
my $find1="PYAG_GENERATED"; 
my $n=1;
my $total_files=47276; #got this no. of files by writing 'ls' command in the terminal
while($n<=$total_files){
open(NEW,"<output_$n.txt") or die "could not open:$!";
my $join=join('',<NEW>);
$a[$i]=$join;
#print "$a[10]";
$n++;
$i++;
}
close NEW;
for($i=1;$i<=$total_files;$i++){
    if($a[$i]=~m/$find1/){
    open(NEW1,">>new_1.tmp") or die "could not open:$!";
    print NEW1 $a[$i];
    }
}
close NEW1;
```